# What's the intuition behind the fact that sample mean and sample variance are independent when sampling from a normal population?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, mean, sample, intuition

Let $X_1, \dotsc,X_n$ be i.i.d. from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then we know that sample mean $\bar X\equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}(X_i-\bar X)^2$ are independent. Obviously, they both depend on $\bar X$ and depend on all observations as well. So this independence result is really surprising. I'm wondering what's the intuition behind this result.

Comment: [Related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422676/independence-of-mean-and-variance-of-discrete-uniform-distributions)

Comment: @Dave Thanks, Dave! It's indeed related, but didn't give any intuition though.

Comment: First of all, having an overlapped part of two random variables does not rule out the possibility of the independence between them.  As another example, $X, Y \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$, then $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are independent.

Comment: For this question, a geometric interpretation can be found in Section 1.3 of the textbook *The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models* by M. Wichura.  At high-level, if view $X := (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\bar{X}e, X - \bar{X}e$ are orthogonal projections of $X$ onto $[e]$ and $[e]^\perp$ respectively, thus are "uncorrelated", which are in turn independent by the normality assumption. Then note $(n - 1)S^2 = (X - \bar{X}e)^T(X - \bar{X}e)$.

Comment: You're unlikely to find any intuition which doesn't at some point rely on yet other properties of the normal distribution (plus what will be some mathematical argument to relate them), for which other properties you'll presumably want intuition (as with the comment immediately above this one,, which does just that - uses a mathematical argument in order to invoke yet another property of the normal which I assume you don't already have intuition for). The normal has a number of properties that are unique to it.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you very much! This is very helpful!

Comment: @Glen_b I see. This is very helpful!

Comment: @Glen_b Indeed, I guess what I asked for was not real intuition, but merely deeper understanding of why this is true.

Comment: This is **only** true for normal distributions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4359/11887

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen You are right!